# Solrj dependency OSGI bundle

Tags: solr, aem, solrj

I have a OSGI bundle that uses SolrJ. I have following dependency in my POM file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
         <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

I am able to instantiate SolrClient on my local

SolrClient solrClient =  new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/content");

But when I deploy it to AEM Apache Felix container on my local it works fine. But when I deploy it to AEM on our dev environment, I am getting

Exception :java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Pleaase show us the full stack trace, and tell us the difference between the two environment.

Answer (score 0):

try using a older version for solrj dependency, if it doesn't work upload the solrj bundle in the bundle console and use your maven dependencies in the Pom.xml